# Como terminar este programa com EOF?

Tags: c

Estava resolvendo um [problema do site UriOnlineJudge](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2534) e foi pedido para que a entrada terminasse com EOF. Fiz o código perfeitamente, com exceção de que não sei implementar o tal do EOF. Como posso fazê-lo?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int N, Q, i, e[101], o[101], d, j, m = -1, n;
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &Q);

    for(i=0;i<101;i++){
        e[i] = 0;
        o[i] = 0;
    }


    for(i = 1;i<=N;i++){
        scanf("%d", &e[i]);
    }
    for(i = 1;i<=N;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=N;j++){
            if (e[j]>m){
                m=e[j];
                n = j;
            }
        }
        o[i]=m;
        e[n]=-2;
        m = -1;
    }
    for(i = 1;i<=Q;i++){
        scanf("%d", &d);
        printf("%d\n", o[d]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apos ler a primeira linha (dois números inteiros) você utiliza o EOF dentro de um while para ler as *n entradas*:

```
int entrada;    
while(scanf("%d", &entrada) != EOF) {
    // ...
}
```